# Transform data in Text file to JSON or XML

Tags: json, xml, xslt, transformation

I'm very much new to JSON and have little knowledge on XML. I have a question regarding data transformation from text to XML or JSON. I've already worked with XSL Transformations, wherein I transform an XML document to either XML or text. But now, I wanted to do other way around, i.e., `text -> JSON/XML`

For example, I have the following text:

```
One(A,B)    One(A',B)
Two(C,D)    Two(C',D)
Three(E,F)  Three(E',F)
Four(G,H) 
Five(I,J)
```

Hence the corresponding XML output may look like:

```
    <B> A,A' </B>
    <D> C,C' </D>
    <F> E,E' </F>
    <H> G </H>
    <J> I </J>
```

I hope the question is clear, if  not please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [XSLT 3.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/) stylesheet you can use with [Saxon 9.8](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.8HE) or Altova XMLSpy/Raptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math fn"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="input-uri" as="xs:string" select="'input1.txt'"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="unparsed-text-lines($input-uri)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="analyze-string(., '\w+\(([^,]*),(\w+)\)')//fn:match" group-by="fn:group[@nr = 2]">
            <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/fn:group[@nr = 1]" separator=","/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks a ton for your response. I'm checking it now.

Comment: I already have Saxon HE 9.8 on my Eclipse IDE, so it should support XSLT 3.0 right? By running the XSLT `I get Resource is not a file: /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS.` Any thing wrong?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse so I can't help with setting it up to use Saxon 9.8 HE and XSLT 3.0. As for that stylesheet, you need to understand that it takes the text input file name/location as the parameter `input-uri` and that it is supposed to be started with `-it` from the command line to start with that template named `name="xsl:initial-template"`.

Comment: oh :/ yes Martin. I gave my filename for the text file in XSLT in the place of input1.txt and tried to run on eclipse. well, Altova is new, I got LicenseServer installed on Mac now and the Cmd line to start RaptorXML Server `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.altova.RaptorXMLXBRLServer2017.plist`It shows no such file or directory [this site](http://manual.altova.com/RaptorXML/raptorxmlxbrlserver/index.html?alsinstallationonmacosx.htm)

Comment: I think if you have troubles to get your software to work at all then you need to take a step back and read the installation and configuration documentation and first try to get a simple example running. I am sure the Altova documentation and if needed support will help with that if necessary. I don't think it makes sense to try to morph your question of doing a particular text to XML transformation into an attempt to get your installation and setup problems solved.

Comment: yeah Martin, I've been working with eclipse, that's why I posted my question for ideas. But now this is XSLT 3.0, which I've never worked with. So I'm trying to get acquainted with it. Well, I understood your earlier comment with a bit of research [here](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xsl/commandline). Hence I'm trying to run it using cmd line.

Comment: Doing it with Saxon 9.8 from the command line with e.g. `java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:sheet.xsl -it` is the approach I know and which should work. As for Raptor, it seems it has a command line option `--template-entry-point` to define a start template, I am not sure how it works if you use the XSLT 3.0 predefined name `xsl:initial-template` or a prefixed name in general, you could try changing the template to say `xsl:template name="main"` and then use `--template-entry-point=main`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Raptor seems to be difficult to get every thing in place. Im using the cmd line.. but getting error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError .... Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read categories.xml file` I google a bit, Saxonica says to use other version. I tried with all SaxonHE 9.80.1/2/3/4. but still the same errors persist...

Comment: Marin: Thanks a ton. I got the solution. Strangely Saxon has been showing such errors on macOS but on Windows platform, it worked wonders. Thanks a lot and lot!! I mean it. I apologise for any kind of inconvenience caused during this process...

Comment: Martin: My final question would be that how to get the XSLT code work, if the second argument value is changing and not the first one (besides the initial case), for e.g., `Three(E,F)` `Three(E,F')`. I would be immensely thankful if  you could share any idea.

Comment: You haven't explained whether that variation of the requirement happens in a different document (where you could then use `group-by="fn:group[@nr = 1]"` and `<xsl:value-of select="current-group()/fn:group[@nr = 2]" separator=","/>`) or whether you have both input types in the same document. I think you would need to ask a new question in the latter case and clearly explain which result you want.

Comment: Hey! My bad, yeah both the cases can be seen in the same document. I presume in that there should be two `<xsl:template match=" ...</template>` statements, one of them being the second case with the statements you mentioned just now! Is that correct Martin? Well, I believe my duty is also to understand this transformation. Since two days I'm going through W3C recommendation for XSLT 3.0 to understand the relevant concepts, but seems complicated to grab a view. For e.g `analyze-string(., '\w+\(([^,]*),(\w+)\)')` is not seen there and I cant understand what the arguments are doing.

Comment: XSLT goes hand in hand with XPath so for (most) functions used you need to look into the joined XSLT/XPath/XQuery function spec. The info page https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-3.0/info has the link https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/. As for the variation of the input data, I am not sure whether the posted solution can be easily adapted, mainly because I am not sure what determines which data to extract. If you can't figure out a solution yourself you might want to ask a new question, showing the necessary details of input variation and desired output.

Comment: thats cool!! I would try to implement the new approach, and if I encounter any problem, I would post a new question. And well, thanks for the link on stackoverflow for xslt3.0. I need not exclusively say, that you have solved my first problem with brilliance :) cheers!! and thanks once again.